# Unable to List Contents or Create Files in /var/tmp Folder from PHP Executed Bash Script

Tags: bash

[I have posted this question here as well](https://serverfault.com/q/1132805/1026963)

**Objective: I want to trigger a webhook on a private linux-machine (its a local system not connected to internet), which can delete the spool data generated by CUPS server in /var/tmp folder.**

To achieve this

**Approach1** I 1st checked the default CUPS configuration files and edited the files there. Lines like in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

```
PreserveJobFiles No
```

and in /etc/cups/cups-files.conf

```
RequestRoot /var/tmp
```

I thought changing the PreserveJob to no will automatically delete the cups spool files once the printing is finished.

Well, Approach-1 didn't worked so I tried approach-2

**Approach2:** I have a Ubuntu 22.04 machine with Apache and PHP installed. I have set up a new virtual host, "example.io," with the DocumentRoot set to /var/www/example.io/

Within this directory, I have an index.php file that successfully serves content to the web browser.

From this index.php file, I am calling a bash-script located in my home directory. The bash script contains the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello, I am above the ls command"
ls /var/tmp/

echo "Hello, I am below the ls command"
touch example.txt

rm -rf /var/tmp/cn*

echo "I am below the touch command"
```

The bash script is being executed, and I can see the output on the web browser for the echo statements. However, I am unable to list the contents of the /var/tmp folder or create a file within it.

Here are the changes I have tried, but none have resolved the issue:

1. I have tried using both relative and absolute paths for ls & touch in the bash-script.
2. I added the "www-data" user to the sudoers file under the "%sudo" line.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/example/script.sh                                                        
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/tmp
```

3. I changed the permissions of the bash script to be owned by the "www-data" user.

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data    6 Jun  6 08:39 script.sh
```

4. I changed the permissions of the /var/tmp folder to be accessible by the "www-data" user.

```
drwxrwxrwt  5 www-data www-data    6 Jun  6 08:39 tmp
```

5. I removed the sticky bit from the /var/tmp folder and set its permissions to 777.

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data    6 Jun  6 08:39 tmp
```

I granted full permissions to the bash script and its parent directory.

When I check from the command line, I am able to list and create files in /var/tmp using www-data user like

```
root@cups-lxc-at-ct:~/instantpost# sudo -u www-data touch /var/tmp/cnijb
root@cups-lxc-at-ct:~/instantpost# sudo -u www-data ls /var/tmp
cnijb
systemd-private-329d46999f134f4a9470ce054ae837e9-apache2.service-iHoe2E
systemd-private-329d46999f134f4a9470ce054ae837e9-systemd-logind.service-lGcUhs
systemd-private-329d46999f134f4a9470ce054ae837e9-systemd-resolved.service-Rqvc7r
```

The ACL on /var/tmp is

```
root@cups-lxc-at-ct:~/instantpost# getfacl /var/tmp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/tmp
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

I checked the AppArmor:

```
sudo apparmor_status
```

I got this output

```
root@cups-machine:~# sudo apparmor_status                       
apparmor module is loaded.
11 profiles are loaded.
11 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
   tcpdump
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 profiles are in kill mode.
0 profiles are in unconfined mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
0 processes are in mixed mode.
0 processes are in kill mode.
```

**=> Interestingly, I have tested the same method with a different folder eg: /usr, /usr/example, /tmp/example, /home/example, etc..., and it worked successfully.**

**I am struggling to understand why I am encountering this issue specifically with the default /var/tmp folder. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).

Comment: 1) Is there any reason that you wouldn't use the cron system to run periodic tasks?
2) Can you please share the rest of your cups configuration along with the directory listing with some of the files? 
3) Have you set PreserveJobHistory too?

Comment: @Quetza We are not using CRON because we don't know, in what intervals we don't to delete the spool files, because the time taken by CUPS is different for different prints. I have downloaded fresh setup of CUPS on ubuntu 22.04 and had not changed anything apart from basic conf. like PreserveJobHistory No , But it didn't worked to my advantage

Comment: You'd need to check that files are not in use before deleting regardless of the triggering method. Using the `-ctime 1` option in a `find` command would work